# How would i disable a text box?

Tags: java, swing, textbox

SO i am working on a project and i was trying to disable the frame and the field from the program so that only the window is front is this one being active 
here is my code :

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.*;

public class password
{
  private static String password = "pass";
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Password");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400,100);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter password");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
    pass.setEchoChar('*');
    pass.addActionListener(new AL());
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
    panel.add(pass, BorderLayout.WEST);
}
static class AL implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JPasswordField input = (JPasswordField) e.getSource();
        char [] passy = input.getPassword();
        String p = new String(passy);
        if (p.equals(password)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct");
            System.out.print("Welcome to Adam's Quirky program.");



        }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect");
       }
    }
 }
```

the program i am currently using to program is Eclipse.

Comment: Creating a `String` from the `char[]` you get from the `JPasswordField` [defeats the purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords).

Comment: Just a few annotation's: 1) Naming of classes begins with upper case. 2) Don't call setSize(), call pack() method (and setVisible(true) after that) and call your frame method's in the end. (I'm telling you this because I was making same mistake's). 3) Your Border Layout has no purpose since you didn't call panel.setLayout() method at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd take a look at a modal dialog.

Either use a `JOptionPane` or roll your own.

If these don't suit your needs, try taking a look at [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) (Java 7) or [JXLayer](http://java.net/projects/jxlayer/) (Java 6 and below)

Have a look at [LockableUI](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2008/07/jxlayer_30_lock.html) (It's a little out of date, but the basic idea is the same)

If that doesn't appeal, you could use a "blocking glass pane"

Take a look at

- [glassPane is not blocking input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761472/glasspane-is-not-blocking-input)
- [Is there a problem with this blocking GlassPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413102/is-there-a-problem-with-this-blocking-glasspane)

as some examples